# How to truly separate logic and UI using PySide

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, logic, pyside

I'm trying to separate logic and UI. In the code below I have UI and logic classes. The goal is to fill the list widget with data - a list of found json files. At first start of the UI it gets data from Data() and fills the list with it. The button which is connected to Data()create() method must create the new file and fill the list with new data. The only way I found to do this is to pass the main window to Data and do refresh which I think is against this model of separating UI and logic. The logic part shouldn't know anything about the UI.

```
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import os
import json

HOME = os.path.expanduser("~")

class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        resolution = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry()
        self.setMinimumSize(resolution.width() * 0.25, resolution.height() * 0.3)
        self._central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._central_widget)


        self._list_widget_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._buttons_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self._list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self._central_widget.setLayout(self._list_widget_layout)

        self._list_widget_layout.addWidget(self._list_widget)
        self._list_widget_layout.addLayout(self._buttons_layout)
        self._buttons_layout.addWidget(self._button)

        self._add_info = Data()
        # Connect
        self._button.clicked.connect(lambda: self._add_info.create(self))

        self.fill_list()

    def fill_list(self):
        self._list_widget.clear()
        for i in self._add_info.get_folder_content_by_extension(path=HOME, ext="json"):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(i)
            self._list_widget.addItem(item)


class Data(object):

    def create(self, main_window):
        data_dict = {"A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3" }
        self.save_json(path=os.path.join(HOME, "new_file.json"), save_dict=data_dict)
        main_window.fill_list()


    @classmethod
    def get_folder_content_by_extension(cls, path=None, ext=None):
        folder_content = list()

        for f in os.listdir(path):
            if f.endswith(".{}".format(ext)):
                folder_content.append(os.path.join(path, f))

        return folder_content

    @classmethod
    def save_json(cls, path, save_dict):
        with open(path, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(save_dict, json_file, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = View()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Separating logic and UI (as with many common patterns like MVC) is not something that should *always* be done. Those paradigms are important and useful, but they should only be used when their implementation actually gives benefits. Does your separation actually provide benefits to your code? Does it improve the *quality* (including readability and maintenance) of your code? OOP is mostly about modularity and reusability, does that separation provide them in a useful way?

Comment: I'm not software engineer and maybe I'm wrong. Maybe after view months it will be more clear for me if the code's readability is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that actually I can connect the same button to `fill_list` method just after it connects to `self._add_info.create`. Separate UI and logic is achieved. I don't know if this is right way.

```
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import os
import json

HOME = os.path.expanduser("~")

class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        resolution = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry()
        self.setMinimumSize(resolution.width() * 0.25, resolution.height() * 0.3)
        self._central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._central_widget)


        self._list_widget_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._buttons_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self._list_widget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self._button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button")
        self._central_widget.setLayout(self._list_widget_layout)

        self._list_widget_layout.addWidget(self._list_widget)
        self._list_widget_layout.addLayout(self._buttons_layout)
        self._buttons_layout.addWidget(self._button)

        self._add_info = Data()
        # Connect
        self._button.clicked.connect(lambda: self._add_info.create())
        self._button.clicked.connect(self.fill_list)


        self.fill_list()

    def fill_list(self):
        self._list_widget.clear()
        for i in self._add_info.get_folder_content_by_extension(path=HOME, ext="json"):
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
            item.setText(i)
            self._list_widget.addItem(item)


class Data(object):

    def create(self):
        data_dict = {"A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3" }
        self.save_json(path=os.path.join(HOME, "new_file.json"), save_dict=data_dict)


    @classmethod
    def get_folder_content_by_extension(cls, path=None, ext=None):
        folder_content = list()

        for f in os.listdir(path):
            if f.endswith(".{}".format(ext)):
                folder_content.append(os.path.join(path, f))

        return folder_content

    @classmethod
    def save_json(cls, path, save_dict):
        with open(path, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(save_dict, json_file, indent=4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    w = View()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```